# Unable to Edit Objects

Tags: mesh, objects, edit-mode, subdivision-surface

I edited several objects but somehow when I subdivided new cube and wanted to edit face it doesn't allow and it shows cube with wireframes or mesh what ever you call it. Please i need help.

Comment: hello, please show some screenshots or even share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: How do i share screenshot or profile. I don't see any options to upload on here.

Comment: you should be able to edit your question and upload a picture no? or use the link I've given, upload your file and share the link (URL) it will give you

Comment: You can edit your question and drag and drop images into it at the cursor position (at least under Windows).

Comment: I've just uploaded the file to the link you've sent me, can you please check if its on there?

Comment: You have to share the given code with us ... copy-paste into your Q via edit.

Comment: Where's the code and how do I find.